# TypeError: undefined is not a function (React Native Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

On my React Native Expo calculator app, I've been getting the error "undefined is not a function" when I try to use the `backspace()` function after calculating the total. The problem lies with line 91: `setCalcText(calcText.slice(0, -1))`, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Here's the full code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Styles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";

export default function MyKeyboard() {
  const [resultText, setResultText] = useState("");
  const [calcText, setCalcText] = useState("0");
  const [memory, setMemory] = useState("");
  const [isOperation, setIsOperation] = useState(false);

  //Occurs when any non-operational button is pressed...
  const onButtonClick = (text) => {
    if (text == "=") {
      return calculateResult();
    }
    if (text == ("(") || text == (")")) {
      setResultText(resultText + text);
      return
    }
    if (isOperation == true){
      setIsOperation(false)
      setResultText(resultText + text);
      setCalcText(text);
      return
    }
    if (calcText == "0"){
      // if (text == "0") return
      setCalcText(text)
      setResultText(resultText + text);
      return
    }

    setResultText(resultText + text);
    setCalcText(calcText + text);
  };

  const calculateResult = () => {
    try {
    setCalcText(eval(resultText));
    }
    catch(err){
      alert(err)
    }
  };

  //Occurs when any operational button is pressed...
  const onOperationClick = (operation) => {
    let operations = ["C", "+", "-", "*", "/"];

    if (operation == "C") {
      setResultText("");
      setCalcText("0");
      return;
    }

    if (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/") {
      setIsOperation(true);
    }

    if (operations.includes(resultText.toString().split("").pop())) return;
    setResultText(resultText + operation);
  };

  const memoryPlus = () => {
    setMemory(String(Number(memory) + Number(calcText)))
    setIsOperation(true);
    setResultText("");
  };

  const memoryMinus = () => {
    setMemory(String(Number(memory) - Number(calcText)))
    setIsOperation(true);
    setResultText("");
  };

  const memoryRecall = () => {
    if (isOperation == true){
      setResultText(resultText + memory)
    }
    else {
      setResultText(memory);
    }
    setCalcText(memory);
  };

  const backspace = () => {
    if (calcText == "0") return
    setResultText(resultText.slice(0, -1));
    try{
    setCalcText(calcText.slice(0, -1));
    } catch(err){
      alert(err)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={Styles.viewBottom}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 120,
          width: "90%",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          alignSelf: "center",
        }}
      >
      <Text style={Styles.screenSecondNumber}>{resultText}</Text>
      <Text style={Styles.screenFirstNumber}>{calcText}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Button title="MC" isGray onPress={() => setMemory("")} />
        <Button title="M+" isGray onPress={() => memoryPlus()} />
        <Button title="M-" isGray onPress={() => memoryMinus()} />
        <Button title="MR" isGray onPress={() => memoryRecall()} />
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Button title="C" isOrange onPress={() => onOperationClick("C")} />
        <Button title="(" isBlue onPress={() => onButtonClick("(")} />
        <Button title=")" isBlue onPress={() => onButtonClick(")")} />
        <Button title="÷" isBlue onPress={() => onOperationClick("/")} />
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Button title="7" onPress={() => onButtonClick("7")} />
        <Button title="8" onPress={() => onButtonClick("8")} />
        <Button title="9" onPress={() => onButtonClick("9")} />
        <Button title="×" isBlue onPress={() => onOperationClick("*")} />
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Button title="4" onPress={() => onButtonClick("4")} />
        <Button title="5" onPress={() => onButtonClick("5")} />
        <Button title="6" onPress={() => onButtonClick("6")} />
        <Button title="-" isBlue onPress={() => onOperationClick("-")} />
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Button title="1" onPress={() => onButtonClick("1")} />
        <Button title="2" onPress={() => onButtonClick("2")} />
        <Button title="3" onPress={() => onButtonClick("3")} />
        <Button title="+" isBlue onPress={() => onOperationClick("+")} />
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Button title="." onPress={() => onButtonClick(".")} />
        <Button title="0" onPress={() => onButtonClick("0")} />
        <Button title="⌫" onPress={() => backspace()} />
        <Button title="=" isOrange onPress={() => onButtonClick("=")} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here's the app on Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@anthonyk/calculator

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this problem by changing `setCalcText(eval(resultText));` to: `setCalcText(String(eval(resultText)));`. I believe `eval()` was converting calcText to a number, rather than a string.